# how to display xml parse value in spinner using android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application,I want to parse two node from url like,

chennai
12

i want to parse city name and corresponding id and display in spinner,when i choose particular city in spinner,display corresponding id in alert box,How will do,please guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are xml is like this,

```
<channel>
<link>
<title> Test Values</title>
<item>
<cityid>
12</cityid>
<cityname>
chennai
</cityname>
</item>
</link>
</channel>
```

then parse these tokens using DOM or SAX and store it in an Array like this

For Instance, If you want to use DOM Parser, then refer this code

Step 1: Create a Method to parse City Id and create an array to store that parsed value

```
String[] cityid=null;

public  void  parse_id() throws UnknownHostException{


        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.getInputStream());
            org.w3c.dom.Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item);
            int a=items.getLength();
            int k=0;
            bstagid=new String[a];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Message_category message = new Message_category();
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(cityid)) {
                        message.setId(property.getFirstChild()
                                .getNodeValue());
                        cityid[k]=property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        k++;
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {         }

    }
```

Similarly for city name,
then in spinner, use ArrayAdapter, if chennai is showed then refer it as cityname array n's elemnt , then you can refer cityid array's n th elemnt, map the city id with city name, like this..